# JBoss 7.1 deployment, classloader issues

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, classloader, war

I have a conventional war project, when I deploy I get sometimes get a class not found error, the actual class not found can alter.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 15 more
```

The jar is present in correct place. It is fixed when I alter the manifest entries. I don't add or remove anything. Just alter the ordering of the entries, so from this

```
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
<archive>
<manifest>
  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
</manifest>
<manifestEntries>
<Dependencies>
org.apache.xerces,org.apache.commons.logging,uk.co.myco.mydep.schema:1_0, com.google.guava
</Dependencies>
</manifestEntries>
```

to this

```
  <Dependencies>
com.google.guava,org.apache.xerces,org.apache.commons.logging,uk.co.myco.mydep.schema:1_0
</Dependencies>
```

Fixes it, its just a change in ordering, there doesn't seem to be a correct order. Its like the classloader gets stuck, and then altering the order of manifest entries unsticks it.

Its not specific to one class, I have had it for different classes. But changing the order of manifest entries fixing it everytime.

This is using Jboss within intellij v14, probably worth mentioning.

Comment: The only correct location for a jar file in a `conventional web application` is the WEB-INF/lib directory. You do not need manifest class path entries for that.

Comment: @SteveC thats not true at all, in an enterprise envirnoment

Comment: Sure it is, unless your WAR file is part of an EAR. If you're using JBoss/WildFly modules then that is no longer `conventional`, because it won't work anywhere else besides JBoss

Comment: @SteveC ok so whats the point of this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html#Modules-1 its the application server providing a mechanism for shared dependencies. Exactly what am I doing.

Comment: @SteveC glassfish has modules functionality aswell, can't be bothered checking whether tomEE does ... but whether conventional or not, is not really the point of the question.

Comment: You would only use modules if you planning on some extensive library sharing between web applications. There are many pitfalls to this however, including the complete absence of annotation scanning.

Comment: @SteveC umm, there are extensive shared libraries.  "The complete absence of annotation scanning"  - eh, our projects successfully use annoations.  None of this is relevant to the actual question.

Comment: I was just determining whether the extra trouble for you is worth the effort. FWIW, I have only ever used jboss-deployment-structure.xml files to manage this.

Comment: @SteveC Good point, I should just use that. Thats fixed it. Thanks.